# Merge c++ obj files for C linking

Tags: c++, c, gcc, stl

I have a huge C/Pro*C project that I want to improve. I copied a piece of it, rewrote it in C++, and it compiles and works fine.

I now want to include it to my C project. In order to do that, I'd like to merge all my little obj files into one, then add it with the others obj files during the final linking.

However, I got errors, and I need help.

- I tried `ld -Ur file1.o file2.o -llib1 -llib2 -o feature.o` but ld complains that it cannot find my libraries (none of them)
- I tried `ld -Ur file1.o file2.o -o feature.o` but then ld complains that there is a huge ton of undefined references to various STL elements.
- I tried `g++ file1.o file2.o -llib1 -llib2 -o feature.o` but it complains that it cannot find main() which is perfectly normal cause I did not want him to make an executable
- I tried `g++ file1.o file2.o main.o -llib1 -llib2 -o feature` and it compiles perfectly good but that's not what I want...
- I tried `g++ -Xlinker -Ur file1.o file2.o -o feature.o so that g++ would give automagically the stl links to ld, but again, ld could not find the STL...`

What should I do, please ?

EDIT:
The main makefile that I wish to change as little as possible contains a list of binaries and their associated obj files. I wish to add my obj file to one of these lists so that the final linking would be transparent.

EDIT2: I don't want to make a library. My new piece of code will replace the old one, and I'd like to use the same kind of process, module by module.

Comment: Not sure what you want in the end.  You could try using `ar` to create a static library with your object files.

Comment: Even if you get a successful merge you are still going to have to use g++ for linking.

Comment: sounds like you're trying to build a library? there are plenty of resources online that'll help you with doing that.

Comment: Beware of *name mangling*.  Many C++ compilers create new names for functions based on their parameters and return types.

Comment: Thomas Matthews, don't worry about that, I already put my extern "C" wrappers for compatibility

Comment: @RichardCritten will I ? I thunk that from the moment avery piece of C++ code would be linked, that obj would be compatible with any obj, like a OCaml obj, a C obj,..

Comment: Hmm..., you really should try to show a [mcve]. With a trivial example, `ld -Ur file1.o file2.o -o feature.o` followed by `c++ main.o feature.o -o foo` actually produces a `foo` executable.

Comment: You can also create shared library file using option '-shared' for the library and '-fpic' (position independent code) for the executable.

Answer (score 0):

To merge object files into a static library you should use `ar`